# Is there a possible way to metamorph human using butterfly method?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, xenobiology

I want to know if there is a possible way to temporarily turn normal human into soup like caterpillar in their chrysalis state as they metamorphose into another being, either biological/chemical or using artificial cocoon machine.

Comment: The caterpillar does not turn into soup inside the chrysalis. It just develops into a butterfly. Some organs grow, others are resorbed, but the basic structure of the organism does not change all that much. The nervous system stays pretty much unchanged, the respiratory system changes a little, the six true legs are preserved (but grow longer) etc. There is never a stage where the developing caterpillar is completely destructured.

Comment: Self-directed (machine-assisted) metamorphosis is a theme in Charles Sheffield's "[Sight of Proteus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1400577.Sight_of_Proteus)" series of novels - in fact it's quite common in society to change form for reasons of fashion or even sexual fetish. He describes it enough to be acceptable to [suspend disbelief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief) - that's what matters, to carry the reader along with your ideas enough to follow the story.

Comment: @AlexP so can that method not a soup one that you has say possible to work for human methamorphosis ? also what the purpose of the cocoon then ?

Comment: @WeareMonica. well iam not really concern myself with the readers in mind when iam join this site to make my question, although suspend of disbelief is one of the element in my question, its more for my own personal curiousity or to learn the possibility or the chance for myself.

Comment: [Human ontogeny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_embryonic_development) is just as complicated, if not *more* complicated. The only difference is that with holometabolous insects the process is divided into two parts, with a free-living stage between them; but otherwise, human embryonic development shows the same processes of development, destruction, and reconstruction

Comment: your major problem is food, water, and oxygen.  all the caloric and water needs of the human has to present from the start, and humans need a lot of both, I would consider it the equivalent of hard exercise. You also need to supply oxygen which means you need mechanical support becasue you can't use the lungs. insects get away with it by being tiny.

Answer (score 7):

The answer can be a maybe, if I stretch it a little.  But the reality is, we do not understand the metamorphosis process of butterflies.  So the best we can really say is "at least one species does it, so we can't immediately prove its impossible for humans."

One of the toughest and strangest bits is the neural connections.  Studies have shown that butterflies can remember things from their larvae stage, which flies in the face of all that we know about what should happen when your neurons all turn to soup. We simply don't know how they do it.

No matter what, there will need to be an infant and toddler like phase of several years in which one learns to control the new body with all its new nerves.  Even in animals which have to be on the move quickly (like prey animals that give birth during migrations), there's a definite "play" period where they're sorting out their brains.  That period would be essential for shaking down a new brain.

Comment: Why do you believe that we do not understand how a caterpillar develops into a buttefly? In particular, the nervous system stays pretty much as it was.

Comment: @AlexP That may be new information.  The last I heard of it was from explorations like [this one](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/03/080304200858.htm) which argued that there was some pretty substantial neurological changes.

Comment: Tristan Lowe, Russell J. Garwood, *et al.*, "[Metamorphosis revealed: time-lapse three-dimensional imaging inside a living chrysalis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3673169/)", in *J. R. Soc. Interface*, 10(84), 6 Jul 2013. James W. Truman, Lynn M. Riddiford, "[The evolution of insect metamorphosis: a developmental and endocrine view](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2019.0070)", in *Phil.Trans. R. Soc. B*, 374, 2019; *"the central nervous system (CNS) provides an explicit case of the larval organ being an arrested version of the nymphal one"*.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, assuming some very advanced science, it seems quite possible. As far as science is concerned, "you" are just the neural connections in your brain, so as long as those are preserved or exactly re-created, "you" are still fine. With that in mind, all you need is either a way to remove and then re-insert a brain into a new form, or a way to exactly scan and then replicate a living brain inside a new form. Beyond that, all you need is a flesh suit. That could be 'donor' bodies (either human or animal) or custom-made bodies, even robo-suits. If this is only temporary anyway, they don't even have to be biologically sound. You could spend a few days in a slowly imploding form, then hop out before it gets messy. Given the low level of understanding in the general populace about the intricacies of neural workings, just vaguely addressing the machines that spin the brain patterns should be acceptable to most audiences. You could probably go pretty in-depth if you really want to explain it. For that I would recommend starting here https://m.all3dp.com/2/what-is-3d-bioprinting-simply-explained/ for info on the current state of 3D bioprinting technology. You might also look at https://science.howstuffworks.com/life/inside-the-mind/human-brain/brain-mapping1.htm for a brief overview of current brain-mapping technologies.

In terms of a cocoon soup, I would say that it's not really necessary if you're using the methods I've mentioned, however you can certainly still have soup if you want to. Perhaps the scanning machine deconstructs the object as it scans, then uses the available molecules to build something new, almost like recycling. That creates the possibility for a temporary soup stage (sort of). It also gives you the option of a dramatic reveal, since a viewer won't see the final form until it emerges from the chamber. Were you so inclined, you could also add a religious element here, along the lines of 'original life.' Maybe certain religious sects view this sort of alteration as the destruction of God's creation while others believe it's alright as long as only the original matter is used (i.e. nothing is added into the recycling machine to create a new form). That could open the door for scandals and low-level conflict all over the place. Just a thought.

So yes, theoretically, given the right technology and a bit of hand-waving, you could have a temporary soup stage while a machine turns a normal human into something else. You can also trade out soup for scans if you like.

Comment: yeah the dramatic reveal and religious element/different perspective is actually part of the plot.

Answer (score 2):

No, because our body doesn't develop like that.

We are too far, genetically speaking, from the insects, to be able to follow that path.

Unless you want to go to something akin to the movie [The Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fly_(1986_film))

> the film tells of an eccentric scientist who, after one of his experiments goes wrong, slowly turns into a fly-hybrid creature.

but there is little science in there.